# Limitations while using orange for clustering

Tags: clustering, orange

I have tried clustering using kmeans in Orange but it looks like there are certain limitations as listed below,
- Supports up to 5000 records only
- no. of clusters can be only 30

Can someone please confirm on this limitation? And is there a way to overcome the same.

Comment: Can someone comment on this? Or there is no one who had hands-on in Orange tool?

Comment: i give up.. seems no one reads/cares this forum.. good luck for others you are eagerly waiting for responses/solution as i did until today... bye